# Filter list elements based on another list elements

Tags: scala, list, collections

I have 2 Lists: `lista` and `listb`. For each element in `lista`, I want to check if `a_type` of each element is in `b_type` of `listb`. If `true`, get the `b_name` for corresponding `b_type` and construct an object `objc`. And, then I should return the list of of constructed `objc`.

Is there a way to do this in Scala and preferably without any mutable collections?

```
case class obja = (a_id: String, a_type: String)
case class objb = (b_id: String, b_type: String, b_name: String)
case class objc = (c_id: String, c_type: String, c_name: String)
val lista: List[obja] = List(...)
val listb: List[objb] = List(...)

def getNames(alist: List[obja], blist: List[objb]): List[objc] = ???
```

Comment: can you provide example input and expected output?

Comment: So if there is any obja, for which there is no corresponding objb, nothing shall be generated at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lookup in lists requires traversal in O(n) time, this is inefficient. Therefore, the first thing you do is to create a map from `b_type` to `b_name`:

```
val bTypeToBname = listb.map(b => (b.b_type, b_name)).toMap
```

Then you iterate through `lista`, look up in the map whether there is a corresponding `b_name` for a given `a.a_type`, and construct the `objc`:

```
val cs = for {
  a <- lista
  b_name <- bTypeToBname.get(a.a_type)
} yield objc(a.a_id, a.a_type, b_name)
```

Notice how Scala for-comprehensions automatically filter those cases for which `bTypeToBname(a.a_type)` isn't defined: then the corresponding `a` is simply skipped. This because we use `bTypeToBname.get(a.a_type)` (which returns an `Option`), as opposed to calling `bTypeToBname(a.a_type)` directly (this would lead to a `NoSuchElementException`). As far as I understand, this filtering is exactly the behavior you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

```
case class A(aId: String, aType: String)
case class B(bId: String, bType: String, bName: String)
case class C(cId: String, cType: String, cName: String)


def getNames(aList: List[A], bList: List[B]): List[C] = {
  val bMap: Map[String, B] = bList.map(b => b.bType -> b)(collection.breakOut)
  aList.flatMap(a => bMap.get(a.aType).map(b => C(a.aId, a.aType, b.bName)))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Same as Andrey's answer but without comprehension so you can see what's happening inside.

```
// make listb into a map from type to name for efficiency
val bs = listb.map(b => b.b_type -> b_name).toMap
val listc: Seq[objc] = lista
  .flatMap(a => // flatmap to exclude types not in listb
    bs.get(a.a_type) // get an option from blist
      .map(bName => objc(a.a_id, a.a_type, bName)) // if there is a b name for that type, make an objc
  )
```